# ActionLink inside button tag does not work in Firefox

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, firefox

This code works fine in Chrome, but does not work in Firefox.  If the `<button>` tag is removed it will work in Firefox.

Is there something I can do to make this work in Firefox?

```
<button>
     @Html.ActionLink("Continue","Index","AlternateName")
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh no, `<a>` is invalid inside `<button>`. That's invalid markup according to the HTML specification. And when you write broken markup all you get is undefined behavior which in addition could vary between user agents, which by the way is what you are observing.

So to make this work, simply fix your markup. You cannot expect a browser to correctly interpret something that is invalid, unless of course you write your own browser.

I don't know what is your scenario but I guess you will have to remove the anchor from this button. If you don't have control over the generated markup (because for example you are using some third party component which spits this invalid markup) as a last resort you could use javascript/jquery to manipulate the DOM after it is created to move the anchor out of this button so that you don't end up with something so broken.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of wrapping the action link in a button tag and formatting the button tag in the style sheet I added a css class to the actionLink like this.

@Html.ActionLink("Add Address", "Create", "Address", null, new { @class = "actionLinkButton" })

Answer (score 0):

Add Button inside Hyperlink tag in mvc, write the Controller and action methods

for passing any parameters: